# Type of an object that has a length

Tags: python, types

How do I type hint a parameter or `isinstance` check an object that must be iterable and works with `len`? I assume that pretty much all objects with a length are iterable, so this is really about what type, if any, represents objects that implement `__len__`.

```
def n_and_list(x: ???):
    return len(x), [y for y in x]
```

It is not `typing.Iterable` or `collections.Iterable` because those are true for things that don't have length, like `zip`.

```
In [1]: from typing import Iterable

In [2]: isinstance(zip([]), Iterable)
Out[3]: True

In [3]: from collections import Iterable

In [4]: isinstance(zip([]), Iterable)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: len(zip([]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-86d411a5426c> in <module>()
----> 1 len(zip([]))

TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()
```

It is not `typing.Sequence` or `collections.Sequence`, because those are false for things that have length, like dictionary keys and numpy arrays.

```
In [6]: from typing import Sequence

In [7]: isinstance({}.keys(), Sequence)
Out[7]: False

In [8]: from numpy import asarray

In [9]: isinstance(asarray([]), Sequence)
Out[9]: False

In [10]: from collections import Sequence

In [11]: isinstance({}.keys(), Sequence)
Out[11]: False

In [12]: from numpy import asarray

In [13]: isinstance(asarray([]), Sequence)
Out[13]: False
```

It's not `iterable` or `iter` because those are not types. It is not `list` or `tuple` because those are much too narrow.

Answer (score 4):

There is [`collections.Sized`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sized) for that:

```
def n_and_list(x: collections.Sized):
    return len(x), [y for y in x]
```

Or for your case, since you want it to have `__len__` and to be iterable:

```
import typing
import collections

def n_and_list(x: typing.Union[collections.Sized, collections.Iterable]):
    return len(x), [y for y in x]
```

Sadly, as the comments bellow mentioned, there is no `typing.Intersection` as of yet to guarantee the presence of both.

Comment: That only checks if `x` has a `__len__` method though. Technically there could be an `x` that has `__len__` but isn't iterable. Edit: `typing.Union` doesn't solve the problem; it just makes it worse. `Union[Sized, Iterable]` checks if `x` is _either_ sized _or_ an iterable; it doesn't require that `x` is _both_.

Comment: `typing.Union` is "or", not "and".

Comment: `Sized` was the main missing piece for me. In order to be both `Sized` and `Iterable`, I'd need an intersection type rather than a union type. I don't know if Python has that.

Comment: `typing.Sized` is also an alias for `collections.abc.Sized`. `typing.Collection` in Python 3.6 inherits both `Sized` and `Iterable` (and `Container`, which asserts the existence of `__contains__`).

Comment: `Intersection` is listed in the [original PEP for type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) under "We might add".

Comment: Sadly, there is no `typing.Intersection` but you can see a good discussion about it as well as a few workarounds [**HERE**](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typing.Collection` if you don't including `__contains__` as a requirement:

```
class Collection(Sized, Iterable, Container):

    __slots__ = ()

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Collection:
            return _check_methods(C,  "__len__", "__iter__", "__contains__")
        return NotImplemented
```

If you do, a `SizedIterable` would be trivial to implement yourself, by just removing the check for `__contains__`

```
class SizedIterable(Sized, Iterable):

    __slots__ = ()

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is SizedIterable:
            return _check_methods(C,  "__len__", "__iter__")
        return NotImplemented
```